# Bigquery query optimization

Tags: google-bigquery

We have tables in BigQuery and there is a query that processes 1.52 TB when run. To optimize the query and reduce costs, can anyone please suggest better ways to optimize it from 1.52 TB to GB?

better ways to optimise of query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at the tables that are being queried. You can likely:

- [partition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)
- [clusterize](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) those tables
- use appropriate filters (`WHERE` clauses) and joins (`JOIN`) to limit the amount of parsed data